# Flutter not picking custom fonts based on fontWeight

Tags: android, ios, fonts, flutter

How to choose different font weights without specifying new family for each weight?

```
  fonts:
 - family: Montserrat
   fonts:
     - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
       weight: 100
     - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
       weight: 700
 - family: MontserratBold
   fonts:
     - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
```

and the widgets:

```
                      child: Text(
                    'TEST',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17.4,
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                  ),
```

..

```
                      child: Text(
                    'TEST2',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 17.4,
                        fontFamily: 'MontserratBold',
                        color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
```

The actual Montserrat-Bold is only used with 'TEST2'. I have tried using 'Packages get' in pubspec.yaml and restarting the app.

Comment: I had this issue too and you need to entirely reinstall the app after changing the assets, (Not hot reload and not only start.)

Answer (score 60):

From [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontWeight-class.html) we get this list of constants:

> w100 Thin, the least thick
> w200 Extra-light
> w300 Light
> w400 Normal / regular / plain
> w500 Medium
> w600 Semi-bold
> w700 Bold
> w800 Extra-bold
> w900 Black, the most thick

So in pubspec you can define your custom font like this:

```
  fonts:
   - family: Montserrat
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
       - asset: fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf
         weight: 600
       - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
         weight: 700
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
final h1 = new TextStyle(
    fontSize: 24.0, 
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600  // semi-bold
);
```

Comment: I followed every step, nothing worked until i uninstalled the app and re-built. then it worked

Answer (score 31):

Font & style settings in pubspec are actually ignored: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36739#issuecomment-521806077

You need to check what weight is described in metadata inside Montserrat-Bold.ttf, perhaps it's not 700.

For displaying the metadata, you can use this site: https://fontdrop.info/, the font weight is displayed under Data/usWeightClass.

Comment: further, you can edit the font-weight here https://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/

Comment: On Mac I edited the font with the Glyphs app. They have a free trial, which was enough for fixing the font.

Comment: I found the python fonttools library to be the best option for simply editing the metadata here. Plus it can be scripted. Here is the relevant documentation on how to use: https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttLib/ttFont.html#module-fontTools.ttLib.ttFont

Comment: See my answer for a full example

Answer (score 11):

The answer by @Jannie Theunissen is sufficient, I just wanted to post here a sample     widget to demo all weights for your custom font. Just in case you want to compare them all and decide which one to use.

So here is what you want to do to check your custom font:

1. Download your font, let's take for example iOS font "San Francisco", you can download it [here](https://fontsfree.pro/base-web-fonts/sans-serif-grotesque/447-san-francisco.html).
2. Put it in your `your_app/assets/fonts` folder (you just need .ttf files).
3. Add it to the `pubspec.yaml` file (*mind the indents and dashes, they matter*):

   ```
   fonts:
   - family: SanFrancisco
     fonts:
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Ultralight.ttf
         weight: 100
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Thin.ttf
         weight: 200
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Light.ttf
         weight: 300
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Regular.ttf
         weight: 400
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Medium.ttf
         weight: 500
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Semibold.ttf
         weight: 600
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Bold.ttf
         weight: 700
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Heavy.ttf
         weight: 800
       - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIDisplay-Black.ttf
         weight: 900
   ```
4. Add this demo widget as a body to your `Scaffold`:

   ```
   class FontWeightsDemo extends StatelessWidget {
     final String font = "SanFrancisco";
     final double size = 20.0;
     final double height = 45.0;

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
         color: Colors.white,
         child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               height: height,
               child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                 "This text has weight w100",
                 style: TextStyle(
                     fontFamily: font,
                     fontSize: size,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
               )),
             ),
             Container(
               height: height,
               child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w200",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
               )),
             ),
             Container(
               height: height,
               child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w300",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
               )),
             ),
             Container(
               height: height,
               child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w400",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
               )),
             ),
             Container(
               height: height,
               child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w500",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
               )),
             ),
             Container(
               height: height,
               child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w600",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
               )),
             ),
             Container(
               height: height,
               child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w700",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
               )),
             ),
             Container(
                   height: height,
                   child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w800",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                   )),
                 ),
             Container(
                   height: height,
                   child: Center(
                   child: Text(
                     "This text has weight w900",
                     style: TextStyle(
                         fontFamily: font,
                         fontSize: size,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
               )),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

And this is something you should get:

[image]

Just thought it may be useful to someone.

Comment: I followed every step, nothing worked until i uninstalled the app and re-built. then it worked

Answer (score 10):

From my experiments, the weight system seems to be doing some clever things behind the scenes. Maybe it depends on the ttf or the device. I would bet though that `FontWeight.w900` might fall into the bold font.

In my code if I specify a weight of 100 (regular) and 200 (for bold), the bold font is not used until I ask for `FontWeight.w500`. I can tell because I also ask for it in italics, and the bold ttf does not italicize for some reason regardless of weight. So while the weights do "thicken" the font programmatically, catching how and why they fall into a specific font seems to require some guess work.

I then tried with 3 fonts: thin, regular and bold and set them to sensible weights in the pubspec.yaml of 100, 400 and 700 which are described in the docs as `thin`, `normal / regular / plain` and `bold`, and now anything *above* `FontWeight.w400` uses bold.

Hopefully this helps, or someone more knowledgeable comes along

Comment: I thinks so, this is very useful information for me. Because I can't make my font works well. I have defined 3 weight for the font regular, 600 (semibold), 700 (bold), 800 (heavy). But when I'm using heavy font (800). The app still using regular font. I can't figure out why and dont have any clue about this. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto @szotp's answer, here is how you can modify the weights for a set of font files in a python script that flutter will respect. Create a `src` and `out` directory, and put the original font files in the `src` directory. The script below will put the font files with the correct metadata in the `out` directory.

```
import os
from fontTools import ttLib

# Declare your fonts and their correct weights here, like below
to_change = {
    'Neue Radial B Thin Italic.ttf': 100,
    'Neue Radial B Thin.ttf': 100,
    'Neue Radial B Extra Bold Italic.ttf': 800,
    'Neue Radial B Bold.ttf': 700,
    'Neue Radial B Book.ttf': 500,
    'Neue Radial B Regular Italic.ttf': 400,
    'Neue Radial B Light.ttf': 300,
    'Neue Radial B Book Italic.ttf': 500,
    'Neue Radial B Regular.ttf': 400,
    'Neue Radial B Extra Bold.ttf': 800,
    'Neue Radial B Extra Light.ttf': 200,
    'Neue Radial B Light Italic.ttf': 300,
    'Neue Radial B Extra Light Italic.ttf': 200,
    'Neue Radial B Bold Italic.ttf': 700,
    'Neue Radial B Medium.ttf': 600,
    'Neue Radial B Black.ttf': 900,
    'Neue Radial B Black Italic.ttf': 900,
    'Neue Radial B Medium Italic.ttf': 600,
}

for file, weight in to_change.items():
    with ttLib.TTFont(os.path.join('src', file)) as tt:
        tt['OS/2'].usWeightClass = weight
        tt.save(os.path.join('out',file))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add or reduce the font boldness alongside you already have `style: TextStyle(...)`

Use `.apply(fontWeightDelta: int)`

For example

```
style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 17.4,
         fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
         fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
         color: Colors.black87,
       ).apply(fontWeightDelta: 2),
```

delta 1 means +100 to FontWeight (delta -1 means -100).
So, this makes you FontWeight 900 instead of 700

> For the fontWeight, the delta is applied to the FontWeight enum index
> values, so that for instance style.apply(fontWeightDelta: -2) when
> applied to a style whose fontWeight is FontWeight.w500 will return a
> TextStyle with a FontWeight.w300.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/apply.html

Answer (score -1):

you need to add proper indentation at `- family`.

```
fonts:
  - family: Montserrat
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
        weight: 100
      - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Parth but I'm already using the correct indentation and it doesn't solve the problem. It's just the StackOverflow code formatting.

Comment: can you put the project on github and share the link

Answer (score -1):

The reason that makes your specified font weight ignored is stated in the [official docs here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts#pubspecyaml-option-definitions):

> Note that defining the weight property does not override the actual weight of the font. You would not be able to access RobotoMono-Bold with FontWeight.w100, even if its weight was set to 100.

The font weight actually is metadata stored in the font file, Flutter does not override this metadata with your specified one.

One possible workaround for that is to change the metadata that specifies the font weight of the font file, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73014825/11217945) to do that.